# Jquery. Splitting an array and updating controls. (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<p id="ID"></p>
<p id="COUNTRY"></p>
<p id="DESC"></p>
```

and my Jquery script

```
var Country = ['100~USA~UsaDescr', '101~SPAIN~SpainDescr', '102~ITALY~ItalyDescr'], p=$('#ID');

$('#slider').slider({
    max: 10, 
    min: 0, 
    slide: function(event, ui){
        p.text(Country[ui.value]);
    }
});
```

I would like upon moving the slider...

For the first slider position update the `ID` control with `100`, the `COUNTRY` control with `USA` and the `DESC` with `UsaDescr`

For the second slider position update the `ID` control with `101`, the `COUNTRY` control with `SPAIN` and the `DESC` with `SpainDescr`

I know i am doing horrible things here, but hey! This is my Jquery start!
For anyone willing to help here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL7Ww/20/)

Comment: What is that array notation you're using? The tilde (~) characters, I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't track properties of objects such as an ID, Country_Name and Description in a concatenated string like that, but this should get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/wUhm7/1/

html

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<p id="ID"></p>
<p id="COUNTRY"></p>
<p id="DESC"></p>
```

javascript

```
var Country = ['100~USA~UsaDescr', '101~SPAIN~SpainDescr', '102~ITALY~ItalyDescr'];

var splitValues = Country[0].split("~");
$('#ID').html(splitValues[0]);
$('#COUNTRY').html(splitValues[1]);
$('#DESC').html(splitValues[2]);

$('#slider').slider({
max: 2, 
min: 0, 
slide: function(event, ui){
    var splitValues = Country[ui.value].split("~");
    $('#ID').html(splitValues[0]);
    $('#COUNTRY').html(splitValues[1]);
    $('#DESC').html(splitValues[2]);
}
});
```

Also, You will need to either do some checking to see if an array position exists or limit your slider max value to 2 in your example. Or else when you move the slider to 3, the Country[3] doesn't exist.